# Solution of the recurrence relation $y_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}y_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$y_0 = 0$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}y_{n-1}$. Solution of this reccurent equation is $y_n = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$, accordingly with the software. But I do not understand the minus sign since it would be $y_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}y_{n-2}\right)$ and so forth until $y_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n}} +x_{0}$.

Can someone try to explain it to me, I'm having a very tough time trying to understand.

Comment: Try to prove by induction that $y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}$ for $n\geq 1$. Then compare this to $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: $y_n - 1 = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}y_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}(y_{n-1}-1)$ and so $z_n=y_n - 1 $ satisfies $z_n= \frac{1}{2} z_{n-1}$. Note that $z_0=-1$.

Comment: @VictorHugodaSilvaSouza I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients) reference may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
y_n &= \frac 1 2 + \frac {y_{n-1}} 2\\
&= \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 2\left( \frac 1 2 +\frac {y_{n-2}} 2\right)\\
&= \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 \left(\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 2 \left (\frac 1 2 +\frac {y_{n-2}} 2 \right) \right)\\
&= \dots\\
&= \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 8 +\dots + \frac 1 {2^{n}} + \frac{y_0}{2^n}\\
&= \frac 1 2 \cdot\frac {1-2^{-n}}{1-\frac 1 2} \\
&= 1-2^{-n}
\end{split}$$

Comment: I thing you meant   $\frac 1 {2^{n-1}}$  indeed it is just a sum of a geometric series, thnks.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure I have the right formula. Try it for $n=1$. Your formula gives an empty geometric sum for $n=1$ instead of the term $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Very clever! I would miss it easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the formula $n$ times: $y_n  = \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8}+\cdots + \dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \dfrac{1}{2^n}+\dfrac{1}{2^n}y_0= 1 -\dfrac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: For $n=1$, that formula gives $y_1=\frac {y_0}{2}$ since the geometric sum is empty. You need to have $\frac 1 2 +\dots +\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ for that geometric series.